# How can I protect my php, jquery, ajax requests from hackers?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I send a lot of data through jquery's ajax method, an example of a function is

```
$.ajax({
    url: retrive.php,
    type:     'POST',
    data:     data,
    success:  callback
});
```

The problem is that anyone can look at the source and see that the location of the php file its sending the POST data to, therefore you could just point your browser there and get data from the URL. I do checks on the data to make sure its the right data type, but I dont want users to be able to go to the url at all.

How can we protect against direct access of that url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to keep a user from navigating to the url show in your AJAX request. All you can do is show an error if you don't receive POST data. You could possibly also set a custom request header with the AJAX request to check for as well.

Comment: if we change type as JSON then, may be retrieve the data if any hacker knows php file ?

Comment: Mmmmm... What about bad/malicious data?

Answer (score 2):

Since modern browsers came with lot of inspection facilities 
this is not being completely possible. 
since php is executed on the server side it will be secure. 
But Jquery and  Ajax can be viewed since it is executed on the client side. 
You can some security measures.

1.) Check HTTP REFERER so that we can prevent unwanted ajax calls from untrusted sources.

in php $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; can be used to check that. If the referer is not 
        from your origin you can reject the request.

2.) Encrypted Urls.

Urls can be encrypted so that the hackers can't get the actual page details.

3.) Javascript obfuscation

4.) Server side validations

Many programmers skip server side validations and just rely only on client side validations. Client side validations are usually done with javascript and it can be disabled on the browser. With inspection tools also a client can alter javascript and perform malfunctions. So server side validation is must.

5) Proper Authentication and Session Management

These are some of the counter measures we can take.Any how we cant prevent a hacker from inspecting or viewing javascript code or ajax calls 
but we can protect our server by rejecting all unwanted requests.

Comment: [Referer checking can detect some attacks but not stop all attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header). I'd also point out that when the attacker is the user himself, then you can only rely on the session and server side validation.